# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid Argument. Unable to write/rename file when splitting pdf

Tags: python, pdf

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
    import os

    infile = PdfFileReader(open('quizzes.pdf', 'rb')) 
    f = open('names.txt')
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines = [x.strip() for x in lines]

    for i in range(infile.getNumPages()):
        p = infile.getPage(i)
        outfile = PdfFileWriter()
        outfile.addPage(p)
        with open('quizzes\\%s.pdf' % lines[i] , 'wb') as f:
            outfile.write(f)
```

When running it says that I am giving it an invalid argument, saying that my path 'quizzes\name.pdf\n'
Not sure why

Comment: `readlines()` retains the newline at the end of the line (as you can see from the error message).  I suggest you use `lines[i].rshift()` to remove it.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. Except that all the pdfs are blank pages. Any idea on why?

Comment: `outfile.write(f)` Perhaps you meant `f.write(outfile)` instead?

Comment: @JohnGordon Tells me "Type Error: a bytes-like object is required, not 'PdfFileWriter'"

Comment: `i` is the current pdf file page, but you're also using `lines[i]` which seems odd.

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes because I need to name the files by the names in lines. Should I be doing it a different way?

Comment: I was asking why the fifth PDF page corresponds to the fifth line in `names.txt`.  There doesn't appear to be any obvious relation.

Comment: Each page corresponds to a name in `names.txt`. @JohnGordon

Answer (score 0):

Well, I dont know whether this is useful, but I think it is correlated.

I got this error:

```
img = mpimg.imread('D:\B.Tech_project2\train_resized\004.png')
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "", line 1, in 
>    File "C:\Users\Naveen tridev\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 1297, in imread
>      with open(fname, 'rb') as fd:
>   OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:'D:\B.Tech_project2\train_resized\x04.png'

I  rectified it by putting an 'r' before the path:

```
img = mpimg.imread(r'D:\B.Tech_project2\train_resized\004.png')
```